# How can I reference an added Method to an existing Class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I extended the String Class with an Method. Let's say 'foo'.

```
class String
  def foo
    puts "Hello World."
  end
end
```

Why is it not possible to call either `String.foo` or `String.method("foo")`?
I am getting an *NoMethodError* when I try.

My ultimate Goal is to pass 'foo' to another Method. Something like `bar(String.method('foo'))`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're trying to call an instance method on a class.

Comment: `foo` is an instance method. You could technically call `String.instance_method(:foo)` which will return an `UnboundMethod` but then in `bar` you are going to need to `bind` this method to an instance.

Comment: For example, `"cat".foo` displays `"Hello World."`, `"cat"` being an instance of the class `String`. Incidentally, though I realize you are just doing some experiments to learn Ruby, when you start coding for real it's generally regarded as bad practice to add methods to Ruby's core classes, such as `String`.

Comment: Although technically possible, it's very uncommon in Ruby to pass method references (in terms of `Method`/`UnboundMethod` objects) around. You typically use symbols to refer to methods by their name. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Maybe with a small example. There might be a more idiomatic solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is an instance method. You can use [Module#instance_method](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Module:instance_method) to get the method, then bind it to a String object using `.bind(string)` and then call that using `.call(args)`.

```rb
class String
  def foo
    puts "Hello #{self}."
  end
end

p String.instance_method(:foo)
p String.instance_method(:foo).bind("World")
String.instance_method(:foo).bind("World").call
```

Output:

```
#<UnboundMethod: String#foo() a.rb:2>
#<Method: String#foo() a.rb:2>
Hello World.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want it to be a class method, you can define it so using `self.methodname`:

```ruby
class String
  def self.foo
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

String.foo    # => Hello
```

You could also make it return a proc so it's passable elsewhere:

```ruby
class String
  def self.foo = -> { puts "Hello" }
end

String.foo    # => #<Proc:0x0000000102a05ea8 (irb):14 (lambda)>
String.foo[]  # => Hello
```

With arguments:

```ruby
class String
  def self.foo = ->(name){ puts "Hello #{name}" }
end

String.foo["Malte"]  # => Hello Malte
```

Comment: Upvote for the shorthand syntax with a lambda (although the first one does not need the empty parens)

Comment: @engineersmnky You need `[]`, `.()`, or `.call`. Without one of those, it's just handing you the proc reference which gets dropped on the floor.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was unclear. I meant the declaration e.g. `->(){ puts "Hello" }` is the same as `->{ puts "Hello" }`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining an instance method, but tried to call a static method.
It works as expected when you call it the correct way.

```
class String
  def foo
    puts "Hello World."
  end
end

String.new("test").foo # output: Hello World.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is, "If I execute

```
class String
  def foo
    puts "Hello World."
  end
end
```

why is it not possible to call either `String.foo` or `String.method("foo")`?

When you execute

```
String.foo
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'foo' for String:Class
```

the error message<sup>1</sup> is very specific: the class `String` does not have a method `foo`. That is consistent with the following.

```
String.methods.include?(:foo)
  #=> false
```

What you have done is create an instance method `foo` of the class string. Let's take `"cat"`, an instance of the class `String`:

```
"cat".methods.include?(:foo)
  #=> true

"cat".foo
  #=> "Hello World."
```

We can also look at

```
String.instance_methods
  #=> [:unicode_normalize, :unicode_normalize!, :ascii_only?,
  #    :to_r,..., :foo, :count,..., :instance_exec]
```

or to find `:foo` more easily among `String`'s 187 or so instance methods, we could examine

```
String.instance_methods.sort
  #=> [:!, :!=,..., :extend, :foo, :force_encoding,..., :yield_self]
```

See [Kernel#methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-methods) and [Module#instance_methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods)

---

If you want to invoke `foo` on `String` you need to write

```
class String
  def self.foo
    puts "Hello World."
  end
end

String.foo
  #=> "Hello World."
```

When the method is constructed `self` equals `String`, so the above is the same as

```
class String
  def String.foo
    puts "Hello World."
  end
end
```

The reason `self` is generally used in place of the literal class name is that it allows the class name to be changed without having to change the method definition. (We obviously wouldn't rename `String`, but we might want to change a user-defined class name (e.g., change `Amount` to `Quantity`.)

Actually, Ruby only has instance methods, so let's look at what `def String.foo` means in terms of an instance method.

We see that

```
String.class
  #=> Class
```

meaning that `String` is an instance of `Class`. We therefore could write

```
class Class
  def foo
    puts "Hello World."
  end
end
 
String.foo
  #=> "Hello World."
```

but this has the undesirable effect of making this instance method `Class` available to all classes:

```
Array.foo
  #=> "Hello World."
Hash.foo
  #=> "Hello World."
```

Instead, we want is to limit the availability of `foo` to just one of `Class`' instances, `String`.

Every Ruby object has a special class called a "Singleton class" (one of several names used). I say "special" because it differs from regular classes in that it cannot be subclassed and one cannot create instances of it.

We can write the following to create a method `foo` that we can invoke on `String`.

```
string_single = String.singleton_class
  #=> #<Class:String>

string_single.define_method(:foo) { puts "Hello World." }
  #=> :foo

string_single.instance_methods.include?(:foo)
  #=> true

String.foo
  #=> Hello World.
```

See [Module#define_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method).

In fact,

```
def String.foo
  puts "Hello World."
end
```

is just shorthand for the use of `define_method` above. Similarly, the familiar

```
class String
  def foo
    puts "Hello World."
  end
end
  #=> :foo
```

is just shorthand for

```
String.define_method(:foo) { puts "Hello World." }
  #=> :foo

"cat".foo
  #=> "Hello World."
```

---

The second part of your questions asks how to pass one singleton method to another. That's easy. We have already defined `foo` on `String`'s singleton class so let's define another, `bar`, that calls `foo`.

```
String.singleton_class.define_method(:bar) { foo }
  #=> :bar

String.bar
  #=> Hello World.
```

<sup>1.</sup> Pay careful attention to error messages in their entirety. Often they will pinpoint the problem.